# ReviewTask for WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

Is their a way to launch the store for reviews in WinRT (C#) - similar to how the reviewtask in wp7 worked?

I am using XAML/C# (Not HTML/JS)

Answer (score 2):

This is achievable in WinRT using the following method:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
    newUri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"));
```

where `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` is your application package name, which you can find in your application manifest file in the `packaging` tab. Note that this only works if your app is already published in the store.

You can find a more in depth tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/egtechtalk/archive/2013/09/03/how-to-include-quot-rate-amp-review-quot-api-in-your-windows-8-apps-by-walaa-atef.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen - there is an automatic Rate and Review command in the settings charm that shows up when your app is published in the store. I think there might be a way to do it from elsewhere in your UI, but I also bet it is not recommended by Microsoft as with anything that is available through charms.